# Error message: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: java, android, resources

I have a very annoying problen. I have seen that some of you had the same issue, but I could not find any suitable answer.

I am developing a very simple app in Android Studio 3.0.1 that can display images and text in a ListView.

I have all my string that I want to display in the res/values/strings as it should be:

```
<string name="ka">ka</string>
```

I also have my main activity and some other activities.

The problem I have appears in my AlphabetActivity, where I try to get the id of the strings:

```
int asd = R.string.ka;
```

This is just a simplification, but this is the thing that do not work. I cannot reach the ID somehow, or there is something wrong, but I do not know what and how to fox it.

I get the following error message:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable japanese.japanese:string/ka with resource ID #0x7f0b004a
              Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File ka from drawable resource ID #0x7f0b004a
```

and the list just goes on and on with "as android.something..."

I would appreciate it if anyone knew what causes this problem, it is very annoying.

And I also checked the R file, and everything seems to be there, so I just don't understand why it cannot find thi ID-s.

Thanks for your answers!

```
public class AlphabetActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alphabet_list);

    final ArrayList<AlphabetContainer> sets = new ArrayList<AlphabetContainer>();
    sets.add(new AlphabetContainer(R.string.a, R.string.i, R.string.u, R.string.e, R.string.o, R.drawable.a, R.drawable.i, R.drawable.u, R.drawable.e, R.drawable.o));

    AlphabetContainerAdapter adapter = new AlphabetContainerAdapter(this, sets);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.alphabetList);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

```
public class AlphabetContainerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AlphabetContainer>{

public AlphabetContainerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AlphabetContainer> alphabet){
    super(context, 0, alphabet);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if(listItemView == null){
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.alphabet_list_item, parent, false);
    }

    AlphabetContainer currentAlphabetContainer = getItem(position);

    TextView alphabetTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);

    alphabetTextView.setText(String.valueOf(currentAlphabetContainer.getAlphabetId1()));

    ImageView alphabetImageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById((R.id.image1));

    if(currentAlphabetContainer.hasImage1()){
        alphabetImageView.setImageResource(currentAlphabetContainer.***getAlphabetId1***());
        alphabetImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        alphabetImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return listItemView;
}
```

}

```
public class AlphabetContainer {
//string source ID for the letter
private int mAlphabetId1;
private int mAlphabetId2;
private int mAlphabetId3;
private int mAlphabetId4;
private int mAlphabetId5;

//image source ID for the letter
private int mImageId1 = NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;
private int mImageId2 = NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;
private int mImageId3 = NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;
private int mImageId4 = NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;
private int mImageId5 = NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;

private static final int NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED = -1;

//constructor
public AlphabetContainer(int alphabetId1, int alphabetId2, int alphabetId3, int alphabetId4, int alphabetId5, int imageId1, int imageId2, int imageId3, int imageId4, int imageId5){
    mAlphabetId1 = alphabetId1;
    mAlphabetId2 = alphabetId2;
    mAlphabetId3 = alphabetId3;
    mAlphabetId4 = alphabetId4;
    mAlphabetId5 = alphabetId5;
    mImageId1 = imageId1;
    mImageId2 = imageId2;
    mImageId3 = imageId3;
    mImageId4 = imageId4;
    mImageId5 = imageId5;
}

public int getAlphabetId1(){return mAlphabetId1;}
public int getAlphabetId2(){return mAlphabetId2;}
public int getAlphabetId3(){return mAlphabetId3;}
public int getAlphabetId4(){return mAlphabetId4;}
public int getAlphabetId5(){return mAlphabetId5;}

public int getImageId1(){return mImageId1;}
public int getImageId2(){return mImageId2;}
public int getImageId3(){return mImageId3;}
public int getImageId4(){return mImageId4;}
public int getImageId5(){return mImageId5;}

public boolean hasImage1(){return mImageId1 != NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;}
public boolean hasImage2(){return mImageId2 != NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;}
public boolean hasImage3(){return mImageId3 != NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;}
public boolean hasImage4(){return mImageId4 != NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;}
public boolean hasImage5(){return mImageId5 != NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;}
```

}

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ////test
    int asd = R.string.bo;
    ////test

    TextView alphabetTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alphabetView);
    alphabetTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_alphabet);
        }
    });

    TextView alphabetTextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alphabetGameView);
    alphabetTextView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent alphabetIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlphabetActivity.class);

            startActivity((alphabetIntent));
        }
    });
}
```

}

I am at the beginning of the learning process, so my code might not be that pretty, sorry for that :)

Comment: Try doing an invalidate caches and restart from the first menu, maybe the indexes are not built correctly... You can also use the gradle sync button in the shortcut toolbar.

Comment: post the code where you are using that id

Comment: I added the actual part of the code which causes the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the problem you string resource of name '`R.string.ka`'. Somewhere in your application you are trying to access with `R.drawablw.ka` which is causing the problem.

or

Try invalidate the cache and re-try.

Comment: can it be the problem, that not just a string has the same name, "ka" but also a picture?

Comment: I have found my mistake, thanks to you I have sceemed once more the parts I used the ID-s, and for the images I also wanted to use the ID of the string. So thank you very much and I am sorry to bother you with this stupid question, as I said I am at the beginnig of the learning process :)

Comment: No problem bro. glad that I could able to help you.